# check box tag binding between controller and the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR. The problem i am facing is that that i have a few check box and initially when i run my app for the first time i want them all to be selected while for every next time i want it to have the last checked boxes checked. To do this, In my controller i have

```
 @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
 @selected_ratings = []
 if !params[:ratings].nil? 
   params[:ratings].each_key do |key|
     @selected_ratings << key
   end
 elsif
   @selected_ratings = @all_ratings
 end
```

While my model looks something like

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_ratings
    @all_rating = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R']
  end
end
```

and the form looks something like this

```
Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, rating==@selected_ratings.each{|s_rating|}
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => "ratings_submit"
```

Now what i am trying to do in the controller is that that i wanted to see if the param is empty if it is then i want to check all the values so i create an instance variable @selected_ratinngs and pass all values of rating into. If i have some values selected from the the checkbox then i save those values in the selected_ratings.

In the view I am planning to use the selected_rating and in the check_box_tag want to compare the selected_rating with rating to see if its already there then the checked parameter is true otherwise.

After such a lenghty description, i want to add that this does not work as planned any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include? worked for me instead

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, (@selected_ratings.include? rating)
```